# Why has TFS build revision number stopped auto-incrementing in 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, numbers, auto-increment, revision

In TFS version 2010 I had no problem using the default build number format "$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)".  The revision number would automatically increment throughout the day.  I have since switched to TFS 2012, and now the revision number will not auto-increment - it is stuck at '1'.  This is of course causing the build to error with TF42064: The build number 'x.x.x.1' already exists for build definition.

Any ideas?  Have I not configured something correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of my build definition began with a dot (.) which caused the auto-increment of the revision number to fail.  Removing the dot, or switching to some other macro like $BuildID, fixed the problem.